# need dimension of solution space of system of non-linear complex equations

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, complex, physics, nonlinear

I've been trying to do this in Mathematica for several days but I'm getting almost *nowhere*. I need to know the dimension of the solution space of each of the two systems of nonlinear complex equations below, where if z = a + ib then zbar = a - ib. The answers would be greatly appreciated!

[z1 z1bar + z2 z2bar + z3 z3bar = 1,
z1 z2bar = 0, z1 z3bar = 0, z2 z1bar = 0, z2 z3bar = 0, z3 z1bar = 0, z3 z2bar = 0,
z1bar z2 = 0, z1bar z3 = 0, z2bar z1 = 0, z2bar z3 = 0, z3bar z1 = 0, z3bar z2= 0]

There are 13 constraint equations in only 3 complex variables but there is a lot of redundancy in the equations. The dimension of the solution space might be 1 or 2 (Real).

And the same thing in 4 complex variables:

[z1 z1bar + z2 z2bar + z3 z3bar + z4 z4bar = 1,
z1 z2bar = 0, z1 z3bar = 0, z1 z4bar = 0, z2 z1bar = 0, z2 z3bar = 0, z2 z4bar = 0, z3 z1bar = 0, z3 z2bar = 0, z3 z4bar = 0, z4 z1bar = 0, z4 z2bar = 0, z4 z3bar = 0,
z1bar z2 = 0, z1bar z3 = 0, z1bar z4 = 0, z2bar z1 = 0, z2bar z3 = 0, z2bar z4 = 0, z3bar z1 = 0, z3bar z2= 0, z3bar z4 = 0, z4bar z1 = 0, z4bar z2 = 0, z4bar z3 = 0]

Comment: Can I quote your code (and name) in a paper that I *might* (or might not) get published in the future?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your solution space is one dimensional.

Toward this aim, we first replace z and zbar by a+ I b and a- I b. Then we expand and use Reduce the get the solutions:

```
eq = {z1 z1bar + z2 z2bar + z3 z3bar == 1, z1 z2bar == 0, 
     z1 z3bar == 0, z2 z1bar == 0, z2 z3bar == 0, z3 z1bar == 0, 
     z3 z2bar == 0, z1bar z2 == 0, z1bar z3 == 0, z2bar z1 == 0, 
     z2bar z3 == 0, z3bar z1 == 0, z3bar z2 == 0} /. {z1 -> a1 + b1 I,
      z2 -> a2 + b2 I, z3 -> a3 + b3 I, z1bar -> a1 - b1 I, 
     z2bar -> a2 - b2 I, z3bar -> a3 - b3 I} // Expand;
Reduce[eq, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {a, b};

repl = Flatten[{(Symbol["z" <> ToString[#]] -> a[#] + I*b[#]),
      (Symbol["z" <> ToString[#] <> "bar"] -> a[#] - I*b[#])} & /@ 
    Range[4]];

eqns1 = {z1 z1bar + z2 z2bar + z3 z3bar == 1, z1 z2bar == 0, 
    z1 z3bar == 0, z2 z1bar == 0, z2 z3bar == 0, z3 z1bar == 0, 
    z3 z2bar == 0, z1bar z2 == 0, z1bar z3 == 0, z2bar z1 == 0, 
    z2bar z3 == 0, z3bar z1 == 0, z3bar z2 == 0} /. repl;

var1 = Outer[#1[#2] &, {a, b}, Range[3]] // Flatten;

(sol1 = {Reduce[eqns1, var1] // LogicalExpand // ToRules} /. 
  r_Rule?(! FreeQ[#[[1]], Power] &) :> Reverse[r]) // Column
```

[image]

Verifying the solution,

```
And @@@ (eqns1 /. sol1 // Simplify)

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

For the second set of equations,

```
eqns2 = {z1 z1bar + z2 z2bar + z3 z3bar + z4 z4bar == 1, 
    z1 z2bar == 0, z1 z3bar == 0, z1 z4bar == 0, z2 z1bar == 0, 
    z2 z3bar == 0, z2 z4bar == 0, z3 z1bar == 0, z3 z2bar == 0, 
    z3 z4bar == 0, z4 z1bar == 0, z4 z2bar == 0, z4 z3bar == 0, 
    z1bar z2 == 0, z1bar z3 == 0, z1bar z4 == 0, z2bar z1 == 0, 
    z2bar z3 == 0, z2bar z4 == 0, z3bar z1 == 0, z3bar z2 == 0, 
    z3bar z4 == 0, z4bar z1 == 0, z4bar z2 == 0, z4bar z3 == 0} /. 
   repl;

var2 = Outer[#1[#2] &, {a, b}, Range[4]] // Flatten;

(sol2 = {Reduce[eqns2, var2] // LogicalExpand // ToRules}) // Column
```

[image]

Verifying the solution,

```
And @@@ (eqns2 /. sol2 // Simplify)

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Can I quote your code (and name) in a paper that I *might* (or might not) get published in the future?

Comment: Yes. However, it would be cleaner if you use indexed variables from the start, e.g., `{z[1], ..., z[n], zbar[1], ... zbar[n]}`